# MySQL results by userd_id?

Tags: mysql

I have the following MySQL database table structure:

```
name        | product         | client_id 
JOHN BROWN | test1.com     | 122 
JANE SMITH  | hosting1     | 122 
DAN JOHNSON | test2.com | 355
```

How to show mysql query results in php in order to get tables with results grouped by client_id. The main point is I need those details emailed by client_id, so in the current example I should get two separated tables fore those two clients.

Comment: Please show us the result set you want to produce.

Comment: This question is very vague my friend.

Comment: pretty clear, he needs a set of records. One per client id that contains all the product and name pairs in one row.

Comment: @adymitruk great, he needs a set of records. Very clear indeed. Guess I was thrown off by his asking for "two seperated tables".

Comment: The communication is not the best, but he needs to email per client. He could do it without group concatinate, but he would already have that by just throwing in an order by client_id.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your table is called signups

```
SELECT client_id, 
GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT name_product_email
ORDER BY name_product_email DESC SEPARATOR ',')
FROM (
    SELECT CONCAT(name, ' has this product: ', product) as name_product_email, client_id FROM signups)
GROUP BY client_id;
```

Comment: I am working on php script that will inform clients about expired products (hosting and domain). Each client has for example: one domain and one hosting plan, and those records have the same client_id. PHP script will go trough all clients_ids and if the date clause if accomplished mysql query should get all products by client_id and send it to me with php mail() function for each client_id. In this example, I should get two email messages, first one with products for 122 client, and the second one with products for 355 client. Therefore I need somehow to group those results.

Answer (score -1):

```
select client_id, group_concat(product)
from my_table
group by 1;
```

will produce output like:

```
122, "test1.com,hosting1"
355, "test2.com"
```

etc

Comment: I have tried that, but i need results like this: 

122, "hosting1" 
122, "test1.com"
------------------- 
355, "test2.com"

Comment: I have tried that, but i need results like this: 

122, "hosting1" 
122, "test1.com"
------------------- 
355, "test2.com"

Comment: Huh? This works for me - I tested it before posting. What version of mysql are you? Also, what exactly Do you want?